# Spark job Issue [java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved]

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, fasterxml

I am trying to run my spark code, but i am running into issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/AsArraySerializerBase;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.IteratorSerializerModule$class.$init$(IteratorSerializerModule.scala:70)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:18)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:33)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.rdd$lzycompute(Dataset.scala:2586)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.rdd(Dataset.scala:2583)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toJavaRDD(Dataset.scala:2596)
```

Here is my pom:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.12</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-paranamer</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here the output of maven dependency tree related to fasterxml (  mvn dependency:tree  | grep -i com.fasterxml.jackson ):

```
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7:compile
```

I have tried some more versions of fasterxml, but they are also printing same exception. Downgrading as well as upgrading the version is not working. 
What should be my next steps?

Update::::

I have updated the version to 2.9.2, but even with that i am getting the same error.

here is the maven dependency tree after that

mvn dependency:tree  | grep "com.fasterxml.jackson"

```
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.9.2:compile
```

Comment: Why do you need a different version of com.fasterxml.jackson.core?

Comment: 2.6.7.1 is not available for databind, so it happened to be different. No other reason

Comment: I have updated the version to 2.9.2, but even with that i am getting the same error.

here is the maven dependency tree after that